# how to do simple collision detection in react three fiber

Tags: react-three-fiber

I don't want to use any libraries. I just want simple collision detection. If it's a raycast in the direction the object is moving I am happy with that.

I don't know where to begin to write code for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=raycaster#api/en/core/Raycaster). It can be implemented in react-three-fiber by using a hook:

```js
import { useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { Object3D, Raycaster, Vector3 } from 'three'

export const useForwardRaycast = (obj: {current: Object3D|null}) => {

  const raycaster = useMemo(() => new Raycaster(), [])
  const pos = useMemo(() => new Vector3(), [])
  const dir = useMemo(() => new Vector3(), [])
  const scene = useThree(state => state.scene)

  return () => {
    if (!obj.current)
      return []
    raycaster.set(
      obj.current.getWorldPosition(pos),
      obj.current.getWorldDirection(dir))
    return raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children)
  }
}
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-raycast-wrsn9i), check out the console for when the array contains hits.

TLDR implementation:

```js
const Comp = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  const raycast = useForwardRaycast(ref)
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    ref.current.rotation.y += 1 * delta
    const intersections = raycast()
    console.log(intersections.length)
    //...do something here
  })

  return (
    <mesh ref={ref}>
      <boxGeometry />
      <meshStandardMaterial color="orange" />
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi @chantey - im using your solution which works great ! would it be possible to tell when the object intersecting is out of the intersection, in / out detection for animating it while intersecting. (?) thanks

Comment: Afik there isnt a stateful version, I think you'd need to keep track of that yourself with another value: `let isIntersecting = useState(false)` etc

Comment: Right, so I ended up adding two Box objects with the intersection hook, so one would indicate the enter of an object and the second would be the exit. That works for me pretty good 